# Install Raspberry Pi for Desktop hangs in boot loop

Tags: raspberry-pi, debian-buster

I have installed [Raspberry Pi for Desktop](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/) on a Lenovo Laptop [following these instructions](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/install-raspberry-pi-desktop/4). The installation ran without problems. On restart the computer hangs in a loop: Every time I am asked in the boot menu from which drive I want to boot.
Here I select the hard disk and after a short time I am asked again from which drive I want to boot...

Anyone have an idea what is going wrong?

[image: Screenshot during installation process]
[image: Screenshot during installation process]
[image: boot menu loop]

Thanks for the help

Comment: Did you choose to install grub, or is it already installed ?

Comment: I was not asked for a choice whether I wanted to install grub. But in the installation routine I saw that grub was installed.

Comment: It looks like it was not properly installed. You would see this behavior if grub was not found or not properly installed, and is not detected

Comment: Ok, but how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Its hard to say without more information, but in the documentation you sent there is a section about installing grub. I would try to reinstall and make sure you look where grub is installed. There are some resource on how to debug grub available, but its usually not an easy task